# Displaying ACF Custom Field in WooCommerce Vendor Pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, vendor, wcvendors

I am trying to display a set of custom fields on WooCommerce Vendor pages via Advanced Custom Fields. For the base vendor functionality, I am using the following plugin: https://woocommerce.com/products/product-vendors/

I have added the custom fields under ACF Field Groups and set the display rules to "Taxonomy » Vendors". With this in place, the custom fields are displaying within each individual "Edit Vendor" dashboard.

Within the vendor plugin files I have found where I would like to display the custom fields, which is on line 210 of the file `WooCommerce Product Vendors / includes / woocommerce-product-vendors/includes/class-wc-product-vendors-vendor-frontend.php`

Initially I tried using the following basic ACF code to display the custom fields, to no avail:

`<p id="sample"><?php the_field('field_name'); ?></p>`

I have also tried saving the field as a variable and then displaying it, again to no avail:

```
<?php

$variable = get_field('field_name');

echo '<p>' . $variable . '</p>';

?>
```

In both of these examples, the `<p>` wrapping elements are showing up on the front end, but the custom fields/variables are not.

One interesting thing I found is that when I use ACF to create an additional options panel within the WordPress dashboard, I am then easily able to display these variables from the options panel within the vendor pages. Following is the `functions.php` code I use to create this options panel:

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
    
    acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Additional Theme Options',
        'menu_title'    => 'Additional Theme Options',
        'menu_slug'     => 'additional-Theme-options',
        'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect'      => false
    ));
}
```

And then within the plugin file referenced as above, if I insert the following script it displays the options panel fields perfectly:

```
<?php the_field('sample_option_field', 'option'); ?>
```

The problem with the options panel route is that these are then global, singular variables and not registered on a per-vendor basis.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to define the term: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fresz, defining the terms worked perfectly. Following is the code I inserted into the plugin file to properly display the custom fields from the Vendor taxonomy:

```
// get the current taxonomy term
$term = get_queried_object();

// vars
$vendorphoto = get_field('vendor_secondary_photo', $term);
$street = get_field('vendor_street', $term);
$city = get_field('vendor_city', $term);
$state = get_field('vendor_state', $term);
$zip = get_field('vendor_zip', $term);
            
echo '<img src="'.$vendorphoto.'">';
echo '<p id="sample">'.$street. "<br />" .$city. ", " .$state. " " .$zip.'</p>';
```